# Custom View For RecentBlogPosts in Orchard

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms

I've been searching and trying for 2 days to change the view for the RecentBlogPosts content type that appears on my homepage. I want to display the title and a phrase from the posts.

I have managed to find a view that shows the title for each post, but I haven't managed to figure out what the other parts in the Model are named or how to extract the text.

Help will be GREATLY appreciated !

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;
@using Orchard.Core.Routable.Models;
@using Contrib.Hyperlink.Fields;
@{


  IEnumerable<object> blogPosts = Model.ContentItems.ContentItems;
}
@if (blogPosts == null || blogPosts.Count() < 1)
{
    <p>@T("No posts.")</p>
}
else
{
   <div class="content-items">
   @foreach (dynamic post in blogPosts)
   {
            string title = post.Title;
            ContentItem item = post.ContentItem;

   <div class="blogpost" style="width: 300px; padding-left: 15px; float: left;">
         <p class="content-item-summary">@Html.ItemDisplayLink(title, item)</p>
   </div>

   }
   </div>
}
```

The above code was (mainly) from [Bertrand Le Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363821/bertrand-le-roy)'s [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/), for which I thank him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ContentItem is a **BlogPost** content item, which contains [BlogPostPart](http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe55d6737a3e#src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Blogs/Models/BlogPostPart.cs) (from Orchard.Blogs.Models namespace). So you can use any properties it has - checkout the link to the source code I provided above.

This part has the **Text** property, which returns the Html from corresponding **BodyPart** (which BlogPost type has attached too) under the hood. 
And btw - Remember to use *@Html.Raw(part.Text)* to display the fetched content.

One more thing - for making life easier I'd rather cast that iterated objects to **BlogPostPart** to get Intellisense:

```
@foreach (var post in blogPosts.Select(p => ((IContent)p.ContentItem).As<BlogPostPart>())) 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

HTH

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, using the foreach above results in :                                            `code` Unable to cast object of type 'IShapeProxy722a7dd4a4ce481a9e164719389c0d7c' to type 'Orchard.ContentManagement.IContent'.                                `code`                                                      Also, is @Html.Raw(item.BlogPostPart.Text) corect?

Comment: Ahh, my bad - I edited the code so it works now. The part is in post.ContentItem property ofc:)

Comment: No, @Html.Raw(item.BlogPostPart.Text) is incorrect. If you'd use that inside the foreach loop I wrote above it should look like @Html.Raw(post.Text)

Comment: Using the modified foreach results in:                                                                                                                              Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ContentItem' and no extension method 'ContentItem' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I modified the code as follows and it works !! (So thank you very much for the @Html.Raw(post.Text)                                                      @foreach (dynamic post in blogPosts)
         {
                string title = post.Title;
                ContentItem item = post.ContentItem;
                var thething = ((IContent)post.ContentItem).As<BlogPostPart>();
      <div class="blogpost">
<p class="content-item-summary">@Html.ItemDisplayLink(title, item)</p>
 @Html.Raw(thething.Text)
               </div>                  
        }
    </div>
}

Comment: Good you have it working:) I forgot to change the IEnumerable<object> blogPosts ... to IEnumerable<dynamic> blogPosts ...  at the beginning (object != dynamic, so the compiler shouted about non-existent property ContentItem, which should be resolved at runtime). As I see you found a solution though - objects in foreach loop are casted to dynamic, so inside a loop you can fetch the ContentItem property without problem (and achieve the same:). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the shape tracing feature in Orchard 1.1 (due next week). The model tab in there will enable you to dig into the objects and figure out the syntax to display pretty much anything.

Comment: Have no worry...I am counting the days till the release and keeping my fingers crossed for more functionality ! Thanks for the heads up !

Comment: The shape tracing feature is a real life saver !!! Thanks ! And congratulations, real improvements have been made.