# Displaying single Fields for a custom ContenType in Orchard

Tags: c#, model, content-management-system, customization, orchardcms

I am beginning to study the very nice CMS Orchard and, after reading the basic documentation, I've stumbled in a little hurdle.
I've created a new DataType, '`SpecialOffer`', which has some dataparts and some text datafields:

```
ProductName
PhotoURL
Price
Description
```

I've made a list, made a widget, customized the `position.info` file and the `Views\Fields\Common.Text.cshtml` file to change the position and the way the fields are rendered (a img for the photo, prepending € to the price and so on) but this doesn't give me the right amount of customization over the generated html.

I've installed the developer shape tracing module and created an alternate `Content-SpecialOffer.cshtml` file.
This gives me the opportunity to easily customize the HTML *around* the content, but I have no idea how to get to the single DataItem fields to display them the way I want.

I mean that the whole SpecialOffer object is displayed through

```
@Display(Model.Content )
```

and, exploring the model, I've not found a way to write something as, say (pseudocode)

```
   <div>
    the 
   <span class="name"> @Model.Contentitem.Fields["ProductName"]</span>
     camera costs 
    @Model.Contentitem.Fields["Price"]
    euros
    </div>
```

I've read this post on SO
[Custom View For RecentBlogPosts in Orchard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514499/custom-view-for-recentblogposts-in-orchard)

but it does not solves my problem, since it uses the standard properties of blogpost.

another little question: other than in the Documentation page of project orchard and b. LeRoy's http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/ where can I study Orchard?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I've found a way to do it:

```
@{
    dynamic offer =Model.ContentItem.SpecialOffer;

    }

     <div>
    the 
   <span class="name"> @offer.ProductName.Value</span>
     camera costs 
     @offer.Price.Value
    euros
    </div>
```

is this the right way?

Comment: hmmm.  smells funny but I see what you're trying to do and heck it works!  Another way would be to do it using client-side script, but that smells funny too.

Comment: more blogs: http://www.dotnetguru2.org/sebastienros/index.php/cat16/orchard/   http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/tags/Orchard/default.aspx

Comment: http://www.szmyd.com.pl/

Comment: Are you actually using fields, or fields access via content parts (i.e. fields against part records)? Fields (as in ImageField, TextField etc) are really for 'non-important' data (B. Leroy posted this a week or so back I can dig the link out for you if you want).

Comment: mdm, I thought that fields were for important, type specific data: "A field is something specific to the type; for example, a Product type might have SKU and Price fields. A part, however, is a reusable component that can be attached to one or more types."  http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Creating-custom-content-types.ashx
but I'd like to read the blog post you mentioned, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.
After the docs and the RSS feed on the home page of orchardproject.net, a major source of information (better than the previous 2) is the source code for the app and modules.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look into it.
My solution, to use DanielEli's words, "smells funny", and I thought that a cleaner, more structured way existed.
Anyway, this looks quite simple and powerful, even if not resilient against a change of theme.
thanks.

Comment: It doesn't. That is exactly why we added dynamic access to content items. How exactly is it not resilient against a change of theme?

Comment: well, if I change theme, the Views\Fields\Common.Text.cshtml file that is contained inside the original theme folder is missing on the new one... so the people who manage graphics themes must be warned not to delete the old one, and to copy the modified views.